# Partitioning a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am working with a `Stream` of `Person` data and I've run into a partitioning issue related to the data.

I have a `Stream` of data which I'll represent below in a table:

```
ID  Name Ticket IsEmployee
1   A      Y        Y
2   B     
3   C      Y
4   D
```

I am trying to return a `List` that is sorted by:

1. whether or not they're an Employee
2. if they have *any* Tickets
3. then by Name

I've looked into `Collections.groupBy` and `Collections.partitioningBy`, but so far haven't been able to come up withe the correct result.

My expectations are to return a list in the following order (by ID):

```
1   [name="A",Ticket="**[100,101]**", IsEmployee="**Y**"],
3   [name="C",Ticket="**[200,201]**", IsEmployee=""],
2   [name="**B**",Ticket="", IsEmployee=""],
4   [name="D",Ticket="", IsEmployee=""]
```

Any thoughts on how this might be accomplished without having to totally break apart the Stream?

Below is what my Person looks like:

```
public class Person {

   private long id;
   private String name;
   private List<Ticket> tickets;
   private String employeeType;  // This is just a 'Y'/'N' value.  This property has morphed into something else but I'm stuck using it.

   public long getId(){
    return id;
   }
   public String getName(){
    return name;
   }
   public List<Ticket> getTickets(){
    return tickets;
   }
   public String getEmployeeType(){
    return id;
   }
   // Setters are the exact same as getters, meaning I have no transient methods
}
```

Comment: Does `stream.collect(partitioningBy(Person::hasTicket, partitioningBy(Person::isEmployee)))` work?

Comment: When you say you've tried `groupBy` and `partitionBy`, can you elaborate?

Comment: A simple example I've tried is:
`personStream.stream().collect(p -> Collectors.partitioningBy(p.getTickets.size()>0);`

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I wish I could use `Person::isEmployee` and `Person::hasTickets`, however the data I am working with (which I simplified above) is a Colletion, so I have to test its size

Comment: Lists aren't partitioned. Are you looking for a sort?

Comment: Show your `Person` class.

Comment: @shmosel, I am looking to break up the Stream.  One of the pieces I am looking to break on is whether or not they have any tickets (I was hoping to be able to do it by checking .size() ).  The other piece is a String value that is either "Y" or "N" to indicate if they're an employee or not

Comment: Your sample output has no breaks, it's just a sorted list.

Comment: Please include your getters as well.

Comment: @shmosel, I've added my getters.   Yes, it's a sorted list, I just meant I didnt want to have to break the stream up by the `Person`s properties then have to put it back together in the order I wanted.

Comment: Can't you use [sorted with comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-)?

Comment: @Dan can you modify the `Person` class to include those methods? `hasTickets` and `isEmployee` are so much better than `getTickets().size() > 0` and `"Y".equals(getEmployeeType())`.

Comment: If all you want is a sorted list, why do you even start talking about “partitioning” et al.? Just collect to a `List` (if a `List` wasn’t you starting point) and sort that `List`.

Comment: @Luke Lee: that might be a waste of time. See, `Collection` has `isEmpty()`, still you ignore it and refer to `size()>0` instead. An `isEmployee` method might have a similar fate…

Comment: @Holger I am fully aware the `isEmpty` method, I was just referring to OP's comment. Anyway, for this question it is a waste of time. But simply because it's example code written to demonstrate the problem at hand, not from real world projects.

Comment: @Luke Lee: indeed, the real world code might already have the `hasTickets` method, but the OP referred to `p.getTickets.size()>0` as the most complicated variant of achieving the same. On the other hand, if the OP is even too lazy to change the `String employeeType` to a `boolean isEmployee` property…

Comment: @Holger, It's not a factor of being lazy, its the fact that this code is common code that other projects use and I cannot just go about changing properties.  It would have downstream effects that I do not want to be blamed for causing.  I did, however, fix the issue with a CASE statement in my SQL

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying “*I am trying to return a List that is sorted by*…”, it’s not clear why you started looking for grouping or partitioning, instead of aiming exactly at, what your problem description is about, get a `List` and sort it by your criteria:

```
// collect into a mutable List, if it isn’t a mutable List in the first place
List<Person> list=stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

// sort by your specified criterie (note: false < true)
list.sort(Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> !p.getEmployeeType().equals("y"))
                    .thenComparing(p -> p.getTickets().isEmpty())
                    .thenComparing(Person::getName) );
```

You can also specify the operation as part of the Stream operation, e.g.

```
List<Person> list=stream
    .sorted(               
        Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> !p.getEmployeeType().equals("y"))
                  .thenComparing(p -> p.getTickets().isEmpty())
                  .thenComparing(Person::getName) )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but there is no technical benefit. The Stream implementation has to collect the entire contents into a temporary buffer internally, to sort it before it is collected (i.e. copied) into the resulting `List`. The in-place sorting of `ArrayList` may get away with lesser or even without data copying (not that it matters for four elements, but in general).

Comment: >  "The Stream implementation has to collect the entire contents into a temporary buffer internally, to sort it before it is collected"  
>
  
You are 100% correct.  I was able to fix the issue within the SQL instead of within Java